# How to deploy a java application if it is used by someone

Tags: java, deployment

I have written a java application, which is used by many people in our organization. I often have to make changes to the application, so i deploy the new .jar file overwriting the existing one, while other people may have it open (i don't know why windows is permitting me this, when it doesn't permit me to rename or delete the jar...). This creates anomalies in the application, and if someone tries to close and reopen it while someone else has it open, the application doesn't start at all.

I know that the most clean solution would be to close all the instances of my appilcation before deploying the new version, but this is near impossible since the application is run by many people (even by customers outside our organization).

What could i do? Is there any other valid solution?

Comment: never just 'overwrite', make sure you create a release with the version in the jar name. communicate that the application will be "down for maintenance", update the jar and configuration.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, is it? It's really a question about institutional software management policies. There are many ways to solve the problem, and I doubt there would be any general consensus, because organizations have particular ways of doing things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a .bat file (assuming you're running on Windows) and let that file point to the most recent version of the application.

When you need to deliver a new version you create a new directory, copy the updated application into it, and then you modify the .bat file.

Another way is to use [Getdown](https://github.com/threerings/getdown)